# Redirect The User After Login

Tags: php

I have a page that only allow the user accessing the page after login. Say that this page is

> http://www.example.com/secret/data/important.php?id=23&pin=2if24scrtw2323.

This is the scenario: When the user access the URL without login, the user will be redirected to login page. My login page URL:

> http://www.example.com/login.php

After successfully login, the user will be redirected again automatically to the page that he/she try access in advanced (in this case: > http://www.example.com/secret/data/important.php?id=23&pin=2if24scrtw2323) Just like facebook.

What's idea behind it? Thx

Comment: use cookies, or use the session (you would have to start it before the login)

Comment: Is there another way without using cookies or session?

Answer (score 2):

You read the url you came to login page. It is stored in $_SERVER unless I am mistaken. (I would advise doing `print_r($_SERVER)` to see what's available) Alternatively, you bring `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to login page as a parameter like so `header('login.php?came_from=' + $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` when you redirect the user to login. Put it in the form as a hidden input. Then after login, you still have that url as a parameter in the script so you can now easily use [header](http://www.php.net/header)('yourpage.php') to redirect again :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to store the redirect location somewhere. This can be done in the url or my preferred option: in a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

store the value of page in cookie

```
$_COOKIE['visit'] = "http://www.example.com/secret/data/important.php?id=23&pin=2if24scrtw2323";
and then from login 
header('location: '.$_COOKIE['visit']);
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to check the id and pin value using php GET and POST or REQUEST like $_GET['id']

after successful login you can set values in session like $_SESSION['id'] and redirect thr user on agin or reload the page and check session value is exist or equel to get value

Answer (score 0):

Please check the php manual for the header method, there is an example for redirection.

http://php.net/header

Copy&Paste from there:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!$_SESSION['logged_in']) {
    header('location: login.php');
    die;
}

//other code

?>
```

Comment: About header, i'm clear here. What I need is how to remember the url that the user visited before without using session & cookie so I can redirect him/her to that page